# Why in the script it's not finding the MainCamera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
interactionObjectPickupLocation = thePlayer.transform.Find("MainCamera/ObjectPickupLocation").gameObject;
```

The main camera is here :
and thePlayer is the FPEPlayerController

[image: FPEPlayerController]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is the best way, but this is the most direct answer, using your code (Keep in mind I might have a typo in a character, as that is a complex hierarchy):

```
interactionObjectPickupLocation = thePlayer.transform.Find("mixamorig:Hips/mixamorig:Spine/mixamorig:Spine1/mixamorig:Spine2/mixamorig:Neck/mixamorig:Head/mixamorig:HeadTop_End/MainCamera/ObjectPickupLocation").gameObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your main camera is *really* a main camera (tagged `MainCamera`), then you can simply use `Camera.main` field to get main camera.

So you can just try

```cs
Camera.main.transform.Find("ObjectPickupLocation");
```

I suggest you to call this function only once, because both `Camera.main` and `Transform.Find()` is pretty slow. One way is caching this in `Start()`, like:

```cs
private GameObject pickupLocaion;

private void Start()
{
    pickupLocation = Camera.main.transform.Find("ObjectPickupLocation");
}
```

Actually the best way is just giving the reference via the inspector, like:

```cs
[SerializeField]
private GameObject objectPickupLocation;
```

Of course there *is* a situation that you cannot do this, but I'm pretty sure (well not *every* though) that the situation where you must use this way is caused by the design failure.